# Сортировка по алфавиту данных из таблицы

Tags: php, сортировка, mysql

Таблица только с одним столбцом в котором названия стилей музыки.
Как вывести эту таблицу чтоб получить вот это: http://jsfiddle.net/L7eKM/

```
mysql_connect('localhost','login','pass') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('All') or die(mysql_error());
$styles = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM style ORDER BY style') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close();

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($styles)){
//Как это сделать?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Допустим, в массиве `$data` содержатся строки, уже отсортированные по алфавиту. Тогда:

```
$data = Array ( 'abcd', 'bcde', 'cdef' );
$first = "";

foreach( $data as $word )
{
    if( $first != mb_strtoupper(mb_substr( $word, 0, 1 )) )
    {
        $first = mb_strtoupper(mb_substr( $word, 0, 1 ));
        print "-- $first --\n";
    }
    print $word."\n";
}
```

Вывод:

```
-- A --
abcd
-- B --
bcde
-- C --
cdef
```

Answer (score 0):

В PHP есть специальный атрибут в запросе, для сортировки по убыванию/возрастанию (нашёл на сайте пример запроса - ***select * from mytable order by name;***)

К сведению есть манул по РНР - [Сортировка массивов](http://php.net/manual/ru/array.sorting.php) (тут всё понятно изложено  по функциям)

Можешь попробовать функцию sort() - пример: ***sort($array)***

Comment: ты не видишь что ли я уже это сделал! Нужно отсортировать по первой букве чтоб получить вот этот http://jsfiddle.net/L7eKM/ список

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT * FROM style ORDER BY style ASC"
```

не?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $x = [1, 8, 3, 9, 6, -8, 12, -51, 41, 54];
     $y = [];

        function number($x, $y)
        {
            if ($x != []) {

                foreach ($x as $key => $item) {
                    $min = $x[$key];
                    break;
                }

                foreach ($x as $key => $item) {
                    if ($item < $min) {
                        $min = $item;
                    }
                }

                foreach ($x as $key => $item) {
                    if ($item == $min) {
                        $y[] = $item;
                        unset($x[$key]);
                    }
                }

                number($x, $y);

            } else {
                print_r($y);
            }
        }

        number($x, $y);
```

Мой вариант сортировки без стандартных функций (sort, ksort, usort и all).

Comment: Переведите пожалуйста на русский. Вы на русском SO.